# ways to invert a specific function

Tags: inverse-function

Given function $y = e^x$, the inverse is $x = \ln{y}$. Is it possible to find the inverse of $y = x*e^x$? If this is not possible mathematically, are tools like programs or numerical methods available to do it? 
I want to put the result, that is, x as a function of y, in an integral.
Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Since the inverse is not  elementary, you might want to see this as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions

Comment: @PeldePinda:  I think there's enough to say about using Lambert's function to solve the inverse here that you could craft an Answer for har.

Comment: It is possible *mathematically,* of course. Well, that depends on what you mean by *find* and *mathematically,* anyway.

Comment: Is my conclusion below correct? I am interested in finding x as a function of y to place in an integral. According to Wikipedia, I can use the following: $x = W_0(y) = y - y^2 + \frac{3}{2}y^3 - \frac{8}{3}y^4$ and so on. The domain  of y is zero to one inclusive.

Comment: Well, no, not for this domain. The series converges for a domain between the absolute value of $1/e$, about .368